# Sendmail Bounce

Tags: sendmail

I have an email server using sendmail. Undelivered messages bounce to postmaster . However the actual message is also included in what the postmaster receives. Due to privacy I do not want this to happen .

Any suggestions?  I have looked to similar questions but no luck

Thanks Tony.

Answer (score 1):

You may add nobodyreturn to PrivacyOptions=x,...
It will stop *your sendmail* from adding original message body.

sendmail.mc:

```
define(`confPRIVACY_FLAGS',`....')
```

To get current settings:

```
grep PrivacyOptions /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
```

Comment: You may ask sendmail related questions at news:comp.mail.sendmail